# How do you put a plot inside a popupmenu that is inside another popupmenu?

Tags: plotting

I have the next code

```
 Manipulate[
     Switch[x, a, If[selection =!= None, selection = None], b, 
        If[selection === None, selection = None], c, 
        If[selection === None, selection = "Hola"]
 ];
 selection, {x, {a, b, c}, ControlType -> PopupMenu},  
 {{selection, None}, 
     Switch[x, a, {"recta", "parabola"}, b, {"hiperbola", "absoluto"}, 
     c, {"Seno", "Coseno"}], ControlType -> PopupMenu}
 ]
```

but I need you to choose the second popupmenu I plot the function chosen.

Comment: it seems to me that something's wrong with the second `Switch` statement there, could you clarify? (wrong number of arguments, the `If` doesn't quite make sense)

Comment: Ok, I change the code, but I do not know where to put the Plot command for each that you can select the second PopUpMenu I plot the option chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I have to admit I do not quite understand what you are aiming for, so here's a long shot...

I understand that you want to have values in the second control (`selection`) that do depend on the first control, `x` that is.

Also, based on the title, I added some plots in the `PopupMenu`. Looks fun.

I hope it helps in some way. The key issue is that I introduced a helper, called `selChoice` to keep track of the updated `selection`-list. `selChoice` has `ControlType` `None`, so you won't see it in the actual `Manipulate`.

```
a = "Algebraicas";
b = "Trigonometricas";
c = "Tercer Grado";

Module[{myPlot},
    myPlot[f_] := Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}];
    Manipulate[
       Switch[x,
          a, If[selection =!= None, selection = None],
          b, If[selection === None, selection = None],
          c, If[selection === None, selection = "Hola"]];
       selection,
       {x, {a, b, c}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
       {{selection, None}, selChoice, ControlType -> SetterBar},
       {{selChoice,
           Which[x == a, myPlot /@ {# &, #^2 &},
              x == b, myPlot /@ {#^3 &, Abs@# &},
              x == c, myPlot /@ {Sin, Cos}]}, None}]]
```

Note that I have no clue what you want to do with the first `Switch`... and also note that I am fully aware that my functions do not quite make sense in the respective categories.

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**

Based on the comment, maybe this is more what you want (I am still not sure)

```
Module[{myPlot}, myPlot[f_] := Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}];
  Manipulate[
    myPlot@selection, 
      {x, {a, b, c}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
      {{selection, None}, selChoice, ControlType -> SetterBar}, 
      {{selChoice, Which[
         x == a, {# &, #^2 &}, 
         x == b, {#^3 &, Abs@# &}, 
         x == c, {Sin, Cos}]}, None}]]
```

Comment: It's similar to what I want but do not want to appear in the PopupMenu graphs, oh and another question Why the first PopUp control does not work?

Comment: The first selection does not show up as plot because of the `Switch` in the body of the `Manipulate` (no idea why you have it there). You can just remove that `Switch`. The remove the graphs from the popup, just don't `Map` `myPlot` on it. Please let me know if that is what you are after and I shall edit my answer (just wanna make sure I correctly understand)

Comment: I don´t understand the question

Comment: @JennyOjeda: please see what I posted in the edit, let me know if this is what you want. I am afraid I also do have some problems understanding the "core" of the question

Comment: Effectively what I want,Thank you :D , but as I am new to Mathematica I have many doubts about the symbols such as @ and & to be used? I looked at the list of special characters but I mathematica solves my doubt.

Comment: @JennyOjeda: perfect. Have a look at e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616, especially that answer and also all the others. There are many questions here that aim at that direction. Good luck!

Comment: Hello again and understanding that means # is used as a variable but takes value of 1, @ is a prefix and & concatenate, but I'm trying to get in equation appears as SetterBar generally TraditionalForm see in class and effectively if but now I get graph, also have declared the function before the code and I get exactly the same, what I intend to do is that in the equation for setterBar subsequently appears to change values ​​and thus move my graph.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. You lost me after "&". All I can say: # is `Slot`, and is used together with `&` to create pure function. See the respective documentation. Thus, `&` is not used to concatenate stuff. The rest, I don't understand (the language that is, sorry)

Comment: I understood a little more about the special characters in Mathematica, but I want to do is to plot the function parameters will be moved.